# Magento - Add global product attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I can not really find a satisfying answer to the following question:

What would be the best practice for a module to add a new product attribute to **all** attribute_sets (and possibly at a certain location).

All approaches I can find seem to refer to adding a new attribute to just one attribute set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a magento way for it
Example:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'test_me', array(
'label'         => 'test Me',
'input'         => 'textarea',
'type'          => 'text',
'class'         => '',
'global'        => true,
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => true,
'default'       => '',
'apply_to'      => 'simple,configurable',
'visible_on_front' => true,
'is_configurable' => false,
'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
'used_in_product_listing' => true,
'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
'group'         => 'Config',
'sort_order'    => 25
```

));

To add attribute to every attribute_set you need to set `'user_defined' = true` and set `'group' = 'your_group_name'`. If needed magento will add your group to every attribute set, and attach attribute to it.

Comment: Thanks, going to try that out :-)

Comment: A quick note: Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute (in 1.6.x) will add your new attribute to all sets (very slowly) if you specify a group name, if user_defined is left unset, or both. If you don't specify a group name, it puts the attribute in the General group.

Comment: Can same is achieved while creating attribute from magento admin. I need to create an attribute that will be added to all attribute set by default.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add an attribute you may assign it to one or all attribute sets, it isn't unique to the first set you assign it to. Does this answer your question?

Comment: What I mainly want to know is do I have to 'manually' go through all attribute sets and add it, or is there some global flag that makes an attribute available to all attribute sets by default?